# racket. add number to a list

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a list

```
(define resultlist2 '(0))
```

and a number.

I want to add that number to resultlist2 element, and using set to keep updating my list

```
(define (adding x y) (+ x y))

(set! resultlist2 (adding resultlist2 1))
```

but i am getting an error here.

i want my result as

```
; before i add a number to list
(display resultlist2)
> 0

; after i added number to list
(display resultlist2)
> 1
```

Anybody have some idea? i think i have to "map" function to add number to list.. might be not ...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just saw your comment and just did it like minute ago. haha sorry for being late!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `adding` procedure adds two *numbers*, but you want to add a value to each one of the numbers in a *list*. If the list has a single element, it's as simple as:

```
(define resultlist2 '(0))
(set! resultlist2 (list (adding (car resultlist2) 1)))
resultlist2
=> '(1)
```

But if the list has more than one element and you want to add the same value to all its elements, then it's a good idea to use `map`:

```
(define resultlist2 '(0 1 2))
(set! resultlist2 
      (map (lambda (e) (adding e 1))
           resultlist2))    
resultlist2
=> '(1 2 3)
```